# Cannot find ant-javafx.jar for OpenJDK 7

Tags: javafx, ant

**Intro:** I am fairly new to ant and I am building jar using a preexisting [`.xml` file](https://github.com/reactome/CuratorTool/blob/master/ant/JavaBuildPackaging.xml).

**Problem:** I have to script its build process, so trying to run it in terminal. The ant build fails after giving following error:

```
default:
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
BUILD FAILED
Problem: failed to create task or type javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:application
Cause: The name is undefined.
```

**Probable cause:**
I looked around for a while and I guess that it is probably a library issue. Javafx is shipped with JAVA provided by oracle, and is not available in OpenJDK 7. A relevant piece of code from the file is as follows and entire file can be found [here](https://github.com/reactome/CuratorTool/blob/master/ant/JavaBuildPackaging.xml):

```
<property name="targetDir" value="${basedir}/../../Documents/ReactomeBuild/CuratorToolBuildFiles" />
<target name="default">
    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"      
             xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
             uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
             classpath="${targetDir}:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar"/>
... some more code
```

**What I am doing:**
I thought maybe I should get the jar file of javafx but couldn't find it.I don't know if I am right in my approach or not. And if there is any official link to javafx.jar file then please let me know.

Comment: Is your OS is Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Yes thats correct, I am running this on Ubuntu 16.04. I also ran it in docker image of maven in which I installed ant. But failed in both cases.

Comment: OpenJDK 7 is not supporting in Ubuntu 16.04. You either has to downgrade your OS to Ubuntu 14.04 or upgrade OpenJDK 7 to OpenJDK 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenJDK 7 is not supporting in Ubuntu 16.04. You either has to downgrade your OS to Ubuntu 14.04 or upgrade OpenJDK 7 to OpenJDK 8. Most probably the ppa you have used to install OpenJDK 7 in Ubuntu 16.04 is out-of-date and not maintained.